# How can I add Custom Woocommerce subheading right below the Product Title on Shop Page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages, woocommerce-theming

I have to add a subheading below the Product Title on the shop page and individual Product Page on Woocommerce on Wordpress. I tried using a plugin for this but it's not giving the ideal result as it's adding the subheading at the last in the product column on the shop page.

This is what the page looks like [right now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMXzR.jpg) I would want this to look like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHsrC.jpg)

Thanks for the help on this one, I am unable to achieve this and it's been a while that I am working on it.